# Convert member class into int C#

Tags: c#, sql

How to convert a member of class into int...example i have a class name "member" then assign it to my textbox age.

**My code:**

```
private Class.clsMemberInfo member = new Class.clsMemberInfo();
txtAge.Text = member.Age;
```

**Error:**

> Cannot implicity convert type int to string

Comment: `member.Age.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you sir! Already resolved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that its the simplest question, and I can conclude it in comment, but I Like the way you present the question that's why paying some attention to answer in detail, really sorry it its an inconvenience.

Let `Age` be a property or field defined as int inside the class `Member`, so it is of type Integer. and through the assignment statement you are trying to assign it to a string value(*such cast is not allowed by the compiler*), that's why you are getting such error message. So You have to use `.ToString()` which will Convert the integer value to a String before assign it to as Text property of the `TextBox`. So the code would be like this:

```
txtAge.Text = member.Age.ToString();
```

Comment: Ok, no problem.. Anyway happy to help you, you can mark the answer as accepted if it helps you